# invalid number of arguments while concatenating SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

```
SELECT 
    HIRE_DATE, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, 
    CONCAT(FIRST_NAME, ' ', LAST_NAME) AS "First and Last name" 
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES
```

I'm trying to get one column by concatenating two other, but i get an error

> ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CONCAT.html#GUID-D8723EA5-C93A-45C3-83FB-1F3D2A4CEAF2

Answer (score 1):

In oracle `concat()` takes only two arguments. You can't use three instead. Here goes your solution.

```
SELECT 
    HIRE_DATE, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, 
    CONCAT(CONCAT(FIRST_NAME, ' '), LAST_NAME) AS "First and Last name" 
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES
```

Or you can use `||` to `concat` more than two strings:

```
SELECT 
    HIRE_DATE, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, 
    (FIRST_NAME || ' '|| LAST_NAME) AS "First and Last name" 
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES
```

Comment: How can i concat so that seperate columns first_name and last_name will be deleted

Comment: @Максим Don't include those separate columns in the `SELECT` list, just use the hire date and the concatenated column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pipe symbol `|` to concatenate strings in Oracle. It can take multiple input columns.

**Syntax** : `Col1 || col2|| ' ' || Col3 || ' Any String' || Col4`

```sql
Select 
hire_date, First_name, Last_name,
First_name || ' ' || Last_Name as "First and Last name"
From HR.Employees
```

You can also use the `concat()` function but it takes only two arguments. You need to useit  multiple times if you have more than 2 arguments.